# Why is Eclipse reporting Interpreter not found when using an anaconda environment with pydev?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have installed anaconda with python 3.6 but I need to use tensorflow for an assignment I am working on.  That means using python 3.5.

I have set up a new environment in anaconda with python 3.5 and everything runs fine from command line but when I try to run in eclipse, if I select the python 3.5 executable, (window --> preferences --> pydev --> interpreter). I get the following when I attempt to run.

[image]

I am using [pydev](http://www.pydev.org/) with eclipse Neon.

Using Auto-Config for 'python interpreters' selection works fine except it does not find the new environment and reverts to python 3.6.

Browsing to the 3.5 executable actually accepts the executable and seems to recognise the packages.

[image]

However, why I try to run I get the interpreter not found error even though I have just listed it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you previously had an interpreter named `python` (you can change the name of your interpreter by double-clicking it in the preferences), and you have either associated that `python` interpreter to the project or run configuration, so, when it's running, it's looking for an interpreter named `python` and failed to find it.

The solution is either renaming your current interpreter to `python` or going to the project/run configuration and changing the association to either use the Default configured interpreter or associating it with the new interpreter by its new name.

As a note, unless you're in some company which uses pre-defined custom configurations, the recommended approach is always using the default interpreter.

Comment: genius!  I changed the name to python and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows --> preferences --> python Interpreter --> quick auto config --> apply`. Follow the Below Image

[image]